# Can i make auto backup for apple devices via Windows Server 2012?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012

I have Windows Server 2012 and I configured auto backup for all computers,
Can I make it also for Apple devices such as (iPhone, iPad etc.)

can any body help me ?

Best Regards. :)

Comment: Have you tried Apple Time Machine?

Comment: @Brandon: Owning an iPhone or iPad doesn't necessarily imply ownership of a Mac as well.

Comment: Oh. Yea i did not see that. I have no clue then.